# Вывод значения объекта в Angular

Tags: json, angular, mongodb, вывод, перебор

Люди добрые подскажите пожалуйста как вывести данные объекта (type: Object)

Нужно вывести именно "name", "shortInfo","fullInfo"

При попытке вывести так {{item.body.name}} как обычный json
Получаю ошибку

> Property 'name' does not exist on type 'object'.ngtsc(2339)
> posts-view.component.ts(11, 26): Error occurs in the template of component PostsViewComponent.
> any

Как это лечится ?

Стэк MEAN. Начну с Mongo, поехали:

БД:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "648802bebb1a6e6e0feb95ea"
  },
  "title": "test",
  "body": {
    "name": "output test",
    "shortInfo": "lorem ipsum",
    "fullInfo": "Full lorem"
  }
}
```

Mongoose Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Schema = mongoose.Schema


const datasSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    body: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
    }
})


module.exports = mongoose.model('datas', datasSchema)
```

Client -> interfaces.ts

```
export interface Datas {
    title: string
    body: object
}
```

Client -> posts-view.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Category, Datas } from 'src/app/shared/intefaces';
import { CategoriesService } from 'src/app/shared/services/categories.service';
import { DatasService } from 'src/app/shared/services/datas.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-posts-view',
  templateUrl: './posts-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts-view.component.css']
})



export class PostsViewComponent implements OnInit {
  categories$!: Observable<Category[]>;
  datas$!: Observable<Datas[]>;


  constructor(private categoriesService: CategoriesService,
    private dataServise: DatasService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.categories$ = this.categoriesService.fetch(),
      this.datas$ = this.dataServise.fetch()
  }
}
```

Client -> posts-view.component.html

```
<section class='FlexContainer' *ngIf="datas$ | async as datas; else loader">

        <div class="app-card" *ngFor="let item of datas">
            <div class="app-card__subtext">{{item.body}}</div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: А если посмотреть в консоль, какой объект приходит при запросе, также можно сделать в операторе pipe(tap(console.log)), чтобы можно было понять что приходит в ответе уже в сам компонент. После этого можно будет как-то понять куда копать